# Fetch events from shared calendar with Office 365 REST API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-restapi

Loading shared calendar from a user works so far. 
However, as soon as you want to load the events, we get the following error message:

```
ErrorAccessDenied
Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
```

The URL looks like this:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/{userName}/calendars/{sharedCalendarId}/calendarView
```

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "$select": "Subject,Location,Start,End,IsAllDay,BodyPreview,Extensions",
    "$expand": "Extensions($filter=Id eq \"Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension.custom.string.here\")",
    "startDateTime": "2018-07-09T22:00:00.000Z",
    "endDateTime": "2018-11-09T23:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Prefer": [
      "odata.track-changes",
      "odata.maxpagesize=200"
    ]
  }
}
```

The following scopes were set:

```
"openid",
"profiles",
"offline_access", // for refresh token
"https://outlook.office.com/calendars.readwrite",
"https://outlook.office.com/calendars.read.shared",
"https://outlook.office.com/calendars.readwrite.shared"
```

Comment: Have you tried to specify a time range fot the calendarView?

Comment: Yes, startDateTime and endDateTime are also set. Note: /me/ works fine so far, but not /users/{userId}. I've added the query in the question.

Comment: this outlook REST way will be not supported by Microsoft, Now one should go with Graph API for the new App creation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Outlook REST API requests are always performed on behalf of the **current user** (authenticated user). That's why the endpoint `/me/calendars` works but `users/{userId}/calendars` does not. You can not get access to another user's calendar using this API. More information is provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/use-outlook-rest-api#target-user).

To access the other user's calendar you should switch to [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/calendar_list_calendarview). Then you could use the following endpoints:

Using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/`

```
GET /me/calendar/calendarView
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendar/calendarView
GET /groups/{id}/calendar/calendarView
```

Remember to specify [permissions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#calendars-permissions) for accessing user's calendars.

Comment: What does userPrincipalName / id means ? Where can i get it from ? can you share a sample?

Comment: @ngCoder The `userPrincipalName` is a user account name (a.k.a. login name) and a domain name in the format of an e-mail address, e.g. *user@example.com* or *user@example.onmicrosoft.com*. The 'id' is an identifier (GUID) of the user in Azure AD. You can call `/users` endpoint to get these values for all users.